# HMS Toolkit cannot be found in Android Studio Marketplace

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-developers

I am trying to Install HUAWEI HMS Toolkit by doing this:

Windows: Start Android Studio, go to File > Settings > Plugins > Marketplace, enter HMS Toolkit in the search box..

But nothing found in the list.!

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can get it. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13220-hms-toolkit/versions

Comment: You can download the plugin and install it via the local file too as described here: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/installation-0000001050145206 If the Marketplace does not work for you.

Comment: Problem could be with your internet connection, especially in Proxy settings. Check your Proxy in File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy

Comment: Just opened a ticket for this, so that the issue will be known.

Comment: I manually installed the plugin , but the android studio reports that the kit is not compatible .Sometimes some other versions get installed but android studio shows this message "Plugin 'com.huawei.deveco.hms' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart Android Studio.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Android Studio are you currently using? As far as I know, HMS toolkit currently supports only the Android Studio arctic fox version. And R&D team is developing the Toolkit that supports the bumblebee version and is expected to release in the second half of this year.

Comment: Exactly, Problem solved by installing Android Studio arctic fox .